# Cocoa и Xcode

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, xcode

Пытаюсь изучить Cocoa для написания приложений под Mac OS X.
Все что не читал, дается с трудом. Всегда было удобны туториалы изучения на примере "кастрюли и ложки", чтобы все было понятно.
Например, на дев сайте эппл интересна статья Your First App. А вот материал в книге BecomeAnXcoder устаревший, поэтому немного тяжко изучить что-либо.

Посоветуйте реально понятные и интересные туториалы по cocoa и objective-c?

Answer (score 2):

[Статья на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/macosxdev/132896/) (она про iOS, но принципы одни и те же, что и для Mac'ов). Вообще, там есть и еще статьи - поищите.
Из сайтов в голову приходит только  touchdev.ru. Ну и конечно, всегда можно вбить в Гугл предмет ваших сомнений и получить список постов разных блоггеров, а так же сообщений в списках рассылки Objective-C разработчиков, в которых он упоминается.

Answer (score 0):

Сам столкнулся с такой же проблемой, нет именно примеров как что сделать. А те что есть только для IOS, для мака ничего нет. Из самого вменяемого под ios есть вот эти [уроки](http://www.imaladec.net/story/content-lessons).

Если найдете что-то стоящее скиньте ссылки. У меня вообще есть идея собрать хотя бы 30-40 работающих уроков и собрать их в одном месте обработать и выложить вместе с исходниками.

Answer (score 0):

Мне в свое время очень помог этот канал на ютубе -- http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDg-YmnNehm3KB0BpytkUJg . Человек рассказывает очень подробно, прекрасная дикция позволяет не упускать деталей.

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите на ютуб, найдите канал AppleProgramming (на инглише правда, но визуально все показано). Там есть плейлисты. Выберетесебе нужный.